# JSON string parsing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I have some JSON which has been passed from a servlet and is stored in xmlhttp.responseText. I want to decompose this JSON so that i can have values of data, size, style, name, etc. Also I wish to have the widget value to be in separate variable.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "widget vlaue=2": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
      "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
      "name": "main_window",
      "width": 500,
      "height": 500
    },
  },
  "image": { 
    "src": "Images/Sun.png",
    "name": "sun1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 250,
    "alignment": "center"
  },
  "text": {
    "data": "Click Here",
    "size": 36,
    "style": "bold",
    "name": "text1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 100,
    "alignment": "center",
    "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
  }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

but this failed. I could not find anything related to it online. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by it "failed"? Did you get any errors from the browser?

Comment: is it something to do with vlaue=2?

Comment: the output is "undefined" for this

Comment: the loop will go as many times as the value. It is a counter value that tells number of children. i have made this JSON string by decoding an XML sent to my Servlet by a PERL file on Apache. Now i have to Use javascript to decode this JSON to display it as some HTML in tabular format.

Comment: what do you mean by "the output is 'undefined' for this"?  What is 'this' and what is 'the output'?

Comment: document.writeln(obj); prints undefined

Comment: @DmitryBeransky undefined is what you get when you try to print a null object in Javascript.

Comment: this is probably better suited as a follow up comment... not really an answer.

Comment: This might sound really dumb, but you do have 'var obj;' somewhere, right?

Comment: @Strelok i would really appreciate the help/hint instead of being called DUMB. I hope a senior member like you was once DUMB too.

About the obj, yes var obj was declared in the above line.

Comment: Lol, when somebody says "this might sound really dumb, but..." that normally is not directed at the person they are speaking to. It usually means "this might sound obvious, but why don't you check anyway".  There is no disrespect towards the person it is being said to.

Comment: yeah your right, I was trying to find a link to comment but couldn't find one so used the only method I had available. I get to comment on this answer though oddly enough.

Comment: @typedef1 dude, he wasn't calling you dumb, relax. Fact is we make silly mistakes or typo sometimes, Strelok was just reminding you that is one thing that you can check. Its just a gentle reminder/hint, I would not be offended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) :

> To convert a JSON text into an object, you can use the eval()
>   function. eval() invokes the JavaScript compiler. Since JSON is a
>   proper subset of JavaScript, the compiler will correctly parse the
>   text and produce an object structure. The text must be wrapped in
>   parens to avoid tripping on an ambiguity in JavaScript's syntax.
>
> var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');

However JSON.parse is still recommended:

> The eval function is very fast. However, it can compile and execute
>   any JavaScript program, so there can be security issues. The use of
>   eval is indicated when the source is trusted and competent. It is much
>   safer to use a JSON parser. In web applications over XMLHttpRequest,
>   communication is permitted only to the same origin that provide that
>   page, so it is trusted. But it might not be competent. If the server
>   is not rigorous in its JSON encoding, or if it does not scrupulously
>   validate all of its inputs, then it could deliver invalid JSON text
>   that could be carrying dangerous script. The eval function would
>   execute the script, unleashing its malice.
>
> To defend against this, a JSON parser should be used. A JSON parser
>   will recognize only JSON text, rejecting all scripts. In browsers that
>   provide native JSON support, JSON parsers are also much faster than
>   eval. It is expected that native JSON support will be included in the
>   next ECMAScript standard.
>
> var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);

Perhaps there is something wrong with your JSON, visit [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) for a free web-base JSON validator.

Comment: My JSON has been verifies from JSONLint. I have been doing that before i cam to Javascript.

Comment: You said it was from a servlet, are you 100% sure that the string was not auto-escaped or modified? I was once using PHP to pass a JSON string and as you may know, the double quotes messes everything up because it wasn't properly escaped in PHP. Since every language has different escape characters, the expected output from the servlet might have been changed. Try printing out the JSON string on the server side to see if it is EXACTLY as you have posted above.

Comment: Well the one above is a similar kind of example. I can not post the exact JSON due to confidentiality. though my JSON has been verifies from JSONLint.

Comment: In your first post, is the JSON copy-and-pasted from the OUTPUT of the servlet, or from some sourcecode that you wrote? I really suspect that the JSON has been unknowingly modified during execution.

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON, that you provided is *INVALID*. Line 9 contains an extra `,` that shouldn't be there.

Here is a JSFiddle that works without the `,`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ApDsP/

Comment: Good eye, indeed I believe that to be the error. Now I learned that I should not 100% rely on JSON validator since not all validators check for trailing comma. (I guess this is because not all JSON libraries forbid it either)

Comment: I don't know what JSON the OP was pasting into JSlint, but the JSON in the question doesn't validate in JSlint either.

Comment: Actually, I **DID** copy and pasted his JSON into JSONLint too, and first time I did that, it worked. Now I just tried again 5 seconds ago, and it **FAILED** (of course, due to the comma in line 9). I think the OP or someone edited the JSON he posted after my first attempt of validating it in JSONLint.